# Как программно установить background цвет круглому View

Tags: android, android-textview

У меня есть `TextView`, которому я указал

```
android:background="@drawable/oval"
```

**oval.xml**

```
<shape
android:shape="oval"/>
```

А в коде я хочу установить цвет. В итоге круглый `background` "слетает".

- Как быть?
- Как правильно указать высоту и ширину круга? В нем только одна буква

Comment: Может уже [готовая библиотека](https://github.com/aamirwahid5/CircleTextView)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17825210/3212712):

```
Drawable background = imageView.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
    ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToSet));
} else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
    ((GradientDrawable)background).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToSet));
} else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
    ((ColorDrawable)background).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToSet));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так создать овал:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="#666666"/>

   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
       android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Size можешь не задавать